# When using pandas to read a csv file it outputs unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'module' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I uploaded a csv file into drive and I'm trying to read it from colab. When I try to read it with pandas it gives me this error. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'module' and 'str'. Any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd
nyc = pd.read_csv(drive/'My  Drive'/'Warehouse_and_Retail_Sales.csv')

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-65c50fb1735f> in <module>()
----> 1 nyc = pd.read_csv(drive/'My  Drive'/'Warehouse_and_Retail_Sales.csv')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'module' and 'str'
```

Comment: Use `os.path.join` to build your path string.  Your code as given just gives `NameError: name 'drive' is not defined`.  Please provide a [mcve] in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas usually takes one line as input to read_csv, what you are doing is passing multiple lines into pandas.

And what is drive ? is that a variable you have declared ?

you would write it something like this:

```
nyc = pd.read_csv('drive/My  Drive/Warehouse_and_Retail_Sales.csv')
```

the simple solution would be, load the file into the directory that you are running the program (or a folder directly below where you are running the program and do the import like this:

```
# Directly in the folder
nyc = pd.read_csv('Warehouse_and_Retail_Sales.csv')

# In a folder below called imports
nyc = pd.read_csv('./imports/Warehouse_and_Retail_Sales.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution. Drive is google drive, a free cloud service by google.